# Qual tipo apropriado para campo que guarda horas no mysql?

Tags: mysql, data

Necessito salvar um campo que guarde horas no banco de dados `mysql`.
É um cadastro de serviço onde preciso guardar a quantidade de horas daquele determinado serviço. Quando ocorre o agendamento do serviço às 11:00 por exemplo, o sistema somar hora gasta para aquele serviço + a hora do início do serviço. Por exemplo, o serviço dura uma hora, então a agenda ficará disponível somente à partir das 12:00. 
Sendo assim, qual o tipo do campo `duracao_servico`, que será somado à hora do agendamento?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No cenário descrito, é semanticamente correto armazenar em formato numérico.

Note que você não está armazenando um **momento** no tempo, e sim uma **quantidade**. Se estivesse armazenando uma posição temporal, seria um caso mais provável para se usar o tipo de tempo (`time`) específico do DB.

Como vai armazenar um número absoluto de horas ou minutos, o campo numérico torna as coisas bem simples na hora de usar o próprio DB para calcular o tempo final:

```
SELECT inicio + INTERVAL duracaoMinutos MINUTE AS final
```

Ou mesmo

```
DATE_ADD( inicio, INTERVAL duracaoMinutos MINUTE )
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f74a/1)**.

Se preferir, use `HOUR` para horas "cheias".

Nota: Se armazenar como `time`, "até funciona", mas tome cuidado com o formato de saída neste caso. Pode ser um pouco diferente do esperado se você tentar usar o `+`:

[Exemplo com `time` no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e65f/1).

Comment: Simples e eficiente.

Comment: Obrigado Bacco.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a documentação do MySQL você tem os seguintes tipos para trabalhar com datas:

- `Date`
- `Time`
- `Datetime`
- `Timestamp`
- `Year`

Abaixo como é feita a representação dos tipos de dados:

Tipo      | Valor

```
DATE - '0000-00-00'

TIME - '00:00:00'

DATETIME - '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

TIMESTAMP - '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

YEAR - 0000
```

Você pode usar o tipo `time`, fazendo sua subtração entre eles.

Ou você pode usar a tipo `datetime`, que poderá  também guardar a data (se está for uma opção). Então fazer o subtração entre os dois campos basta usar a função timediff:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2016-10-12 12:01:00', '2016-10-12 12:00:00')) diff;
```

---

Referências:

[Documentação MySQL (site)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html)

[MySQL: how to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/mysql-how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com o manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) o campo Time é específico para guardar horas/minutos/segundos no seguinte formato:

```
HH:MM:SS
```

Você pode recuperar os dados em outro formato usando:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(foo_hour, '%H:%i') FROM bar
```

Caso queira gravar também a data, você pode colocar as duas em um campo datetime e usar a função DATE_FORMAT para obter somente a data ou somente a hora conforme:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score -2):

Trabalhe com o tipo **Time** e assim consegue manipular horas exactas.